# Filter for generic type without reflection or casting

Tags: generics, kotlin, reification

In Kotlin there is a limited form of [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Is there any way to use reification to filter for a generic type without using `getClass()` or `as` or any kind of weird annotation, ie. just by using the `is` keyword? For example, I have the following structure:

```
import java.util.*

internal class Layout<out T : LayoutProtocol>(val t: T) {
    fun getName(): String {
        return t.getName()
    }
}

interface LayoutProtocol {
    fun getName(): String
}

internal class Vertical : LayoutProtocol {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "Vertical"
    }
}

internal class Horizontal : LayoutProtocol {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "Horizontal"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val layouts = LinkedList<Layout<*>>()
    layouts.add(Layout<Horizontal>(Horizontal()))
    layouts.add(Layout<Vertical>(Vertical()))
    println("Horizontal layouts:")
    layouts.filterIsInstance<Layout<Horizontal>>().forEach { println(it.getName()) }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Horizontal layouts:
Horizontal
Vertical
```

I would like it to output the following. Is there any way to get:

```
Horizontal layouts:
Horizontal
```

If we look at the source code for `filterIsInstance(...)`, Kotlin does some tricky stuff to circumvent type erasure, but still does not work:

```
/**
 * Returns a list containing all elements that are instances of specified type parameter R.
 */
public inline fun <reified R> Iterable<*>.filterIsInstance(): List<@kotlin.internal.NoInfer R> {
    return filterIsInstanceTo(ArrayList<R>())
}

/**
 * Appends all elements that are instances of specified type parameter R to the given [destination].
 */
public inline fun <reified R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<*>.filterIsInstanceTo(destination: C): C {
    for (element in this) if (element is R) destination.add(element)
    return destination
}
```

If this is not possible in Kotlin, is there any language (JVM or non-JVM) that lets me do something like the following:

```
inline fun <reified R: LayoutProtocol> filterVerticals(from: Iterable<Layout<R>>): Iterable<Layout<Vertical>> {
    val dest = ArrayList<Layout<Vertical>>()

    for (element in from)
        if (element is Layout<Vertical>)
            dest.add(element)

    return dest
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this because of type erasure, but if you really want and performance/readability/error-proneness is not something you are worried about, you can do a few tricks:

First, let's add a factory method to `Layout` to preserve erased type

```
open internal class Layout<T : LayoutProtocol>(val t: T) {
  ...
  companion object {
    inline fun <reified T: LayoutProtocol> create(instance: T): Layout<T> {
      return object: Layout<T>(instance) {}
    }
  }
}
```

(note: here I removed out variance for simplicity)

Second, you need a helper class

```
open class TypeLiteral<T> {
  val type: Type = getSuperclassTypeParameter(javaClass)

  companion object {
    fun getSuperclassTypeParameter(subclass: Class<*>) =
      (subclass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
  }
}
```

(note: the same approach is used by [Guice DI](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html), it contains a production-ready `TypeLiteral` implementation )

And, finally our own filter method

```
inline fun <reified R> Iterable<*>.genericFilterIsInstance() where R : Any =
  filterIsInstance<R>()
  .filter { object : TypeLiteral<R>() {}.type == it.javaClass.genericSuperclass }
```

And now it prints exactly what you want

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val layouts = LinkedList<Layout<*>>()
  layouts.add(Layout.create(Horizontal()))
  layouts.add(Layout.create(Vertical()))
  println("Horizontal layouts:")
  layouts.genericFilterIsInstance<Layout<Horizontal>>().forEach { println(it.getName()) }
  /* prints:
  Horizontal layouts:
  Horizontal
   */
}
```

But please, don't use this answer in production code. In real life passing a class instance for filtering would always be preferable.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want! But how can you prevent someone from calling the constructor for Layout? Or is there a way to avoid `Layout.create(...)`?

Comment: @breandan Layout.create is needed as a convenient method for creating `Layout`  subclasses. It's necessary for preserving type information.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter `layouts` LinkedList by `t: T` property of your Layout class.

```
layouts.filter { it.t is Horizontal }.forEach { println(it.getName()) }
```

It will print exactly what you want. I.E.

```
Horizontal layouts:
Horizontal
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the reason `filterIsInstance` does not work is because the list only contains `Layout<*>` instances. You would need to create subclasses to distinguish them through reflection.

Comment: Thanks! But what if the thing you are filtering for is a parameterized type? How do I get something like this? `layouts.filter { it is Layout<Horizontal> }.forEach { println(it.getName()) }`

Comment: Additionally, `layouts.filter { it.t is Horizontal }` returns `List<Layout<*>>`, not a `List<Layout<Horizontal>>`, so in order to convert this to the correctly typed version, we will need to use an unchecked cast, ie. `layouts.filter { it.t is Horizontal }.map { it as Layout<Horizontal> }`.

Comment: What I really need is a function with the following type signature `fun <T : LayoutProtocol> filterLayouts(from: Iterable<Layout<*>>): Iterable<Layout<T>>`.

Comment: @breandan then just declare that function: `fun <T : LayoutProtocol> Iterable<Layout<*>>.filterLayouts() = filter { it.t is T } as Iterable<Layout<T>>`

Comment: @Ilya This returns a compiler error: `Error:(51, 81) Kotlin: Cannot check for instance of erased type: T`

Comment: Oh, yes, like the `filterIsInstance` this function has to be `inline` and its `T` parameter has to be `reified` to be able to use `T` for is checks: `inline fun <reified T : LayoutProtocol> ...`